# How do I check the version of socket.io and update it

Tags: socket.io, socket.io-1.0

how can I check the version of socket.io that I am using ? and how do I update it if there is new release.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1. Download [npm](https://nodejs.org/download/), the NodeJS Package Manager
2. Install npm
3. Open the terminal and execute the following command to install socket.io

   ```
   npm install socket.io
   ```
4. When you want to update it, execute the following command on the terminal

   ```
   npm update socket.io
   ```

Alternatively you can execute

```
 npm update -g
```

in order to update globally installed packages.

---

To find out what is the current version execute `npm list socket.io`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the socket.io version in node_modules->socket.io->package.json and there will be "version": "your version of socket.io".